# Filter by Attribute not filtering on shop page

Tags: woocommerce

I’ve developed a new theme for a website, but i seem to have a problem related to widget Filter By Attribute.

When i use the filter, that comes with the gutenberg block editor for widgets, the filter attribute widget doesn’t filter anything. (i guess it uses ajax to filter, but its not filtering anything)

When i use the `add_filter('use_widgets_block_editor', '__return_false');` to remove the gutenberg and use a new filter by attribute (which is a different widget, than the one that comes with Gutenberg), the widget works, because it filters the query by passing some params on the url, but has a problem. It shows variations that are out of stock, which is something that have been fixed with the new widget, using the product lookup tables, and it's exactly what i'm trying to achieve here.

I strongly believe this is related to the AJAX call it uses to filter the shop page, so i guess i'm missing an ID or Class, to the product wrapper or something.

Does anyone also had this problem?

If you want to see the page in question, is this one https://www.hiima-store.com/bch/shop/
When you go into Filters, you can see both widgets there. (there are two for sizes. the first one uses query params and the second one, is the one that is not filtering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a custom script regarding that.
It might help someone with the same problem.

It will hide the product if the variation is out of stock.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'out_of_stock_variations_loop');
function out_of_stock_variations_loop()
{
    global $product;
    if (isset($_GET["filter_size"])) { // check if the attribute is in the url
        if ($product->product_type == 'variable') {
            $available = $product->get_available_variations();
            if ($available) foreach ($available as $instockvar) {
                if (isset($instockvar['attributes']['attribute_pa_' . __('size', 'hiima')])) {
                    var_dump('entrei');
                    if (($instockvar['attributes']['attribute_pa_.' . __('size', 'hiima')] == $_GET['filter_size']) && (!$instockvar['max_qty'] > 0)) {
                        global $product;
                        $id = $product->get_id();
                        echo "<style>.post-$id{display: none}</style>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
            global $product;
            $id = $product->get_id();
            echo "<style>.post-$id{display: none}</style>";
        }
    }
}
```